# remove all elements in list that do not end in a number in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to sort an array that I have by removing lines that do not finish in a 1, 2, or 3.
So far I've not been very successful and the code I've come up with looks like this:

these lines set the variables to be used in the function

```
import numpy as np

A=[]
B=[]
C=[]
file = open('glycine_30c.data', 'r')
bondsfile = open('glycine_30c.bonds', 'r')
```

these lines read the .data and .bonds files into arrays

```
for lines in file:
    eq = lines.split()
    A.append(str(eq))

for x in bondsfile:
    bon = x.split()
    B.append(str(bon))
```

these lines are here to (hopefully) delete all elements in the list "B" that don't end in a 1,2, or 3 and then append them to a new list "C" although that's not really necessary

```
for n in range(len(B)):
    if B[n].endswith(1,2,3) == True:
        C.append (B[n])
print C
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thank you

Comment: what's wrong with what you got then?

Comment: Why are you passing integers to `str.endswith`?

Comment: `B[n].endswith(1,2,3)` - What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for `endswith()` explains:

```
endswith(...)
    S.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]]) -> bool

    Return True if S ends with the specified suffix, False otherwise.
    With optional start, test S beginning at that position.
    With optional end, stop comparing S at that position.
    suffix can also be a tuple of strings to try.
```

I.e. calling

```
B[n].endswith(1,2,3)
```

won't actually check whether `B[n]` ends with any of 1, 2, 3. What you probably want instead is something along the lines of

```
B[n].endswith(("1", "2", "3"))
```

I.e. passing a single tuple argument.

Comment: how about just str(B[n]).endswith(('1', '2', '3')), ends with accepts a tuple.

Comment: @ilent2: D'oh - did that now; I forgot to replace my first (`any`-based version) with what I learned from actually looking up the `endswith` documentation. :-)